# Solving a formula with decimal values of x and plotting the results

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to obtain `y` for `x` values `[250.5(first), 50.5(last), -10(increment)]`:

```
y = 100 * exp(-5000/x)
```

and, then, plot it. I did

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in numpy.arange(250.5, 50.5, -10):
    print(i, 100 * exp(-5000/i))
plt.plot(i, y)
plt.show()
```

But it gets error as:

> NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined

I appreciate if someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You've imported numpy as np, but in the code you are using `numpy.arange`, you need to change this to `np.arange`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But I still don't get any plot. Do you know how I can solve this.

Comment: Do you mean the figure is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many errors in the code to go through them one by one. 
To plot the curve you want you would evaluate the function you have on an array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(250.5, 50.5, -10)
y = 100 * np.exp(-5000/x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you did

```
 import the numpy as np
```

then you should use np instead of numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in np.arange(250.5, 50.5, -10):
    print(i, 100 * exp(-5000/i))
plt.plot(i, y)
plt.show()
```